# The morphism introduced by a linear system

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I was reviewing the relation of a base point free linear system $|D|$ on a curve $X$ with the associated morphism $\phi: X \to P^{n}$. I know that this $\phi$ may not be an embedding in general, but when it is? If $D$ is very ample, is this $\phi$ an embedding?

In particular, if $\phi: X \to \mathbb{P^{1}}$, this has to be a dominant morphism, is it always the case that $\phi$ is actually an isomorphism? Or do we require any other other condition on $|D|$ to obtain that isomorphism (like degee of $\phi=1$)?

Any idea or answer will be helpful!

Comment: I thought $\phi$ being a closed embedding was the definition of $D$ being very ample.

Comment: Also, most curves are not isomorphic to $\mathbb{P}^1$, but most will have plenty of morphisms to $\mathbb{P}^1$.  For example, an elliptic curve corresponding to $y^2 = x^3 + ax + b$ will have partial map $(x, y) \mapsto x$, and this extends (uniquely) to a map of the full elliptic curve to $\mathbb{P}^1$ by the valuative criterion of properness.

Comment: Yes, I remember the definition of $D$ to be very ample, it does require an embedding. But if we want to determine a morphism is an embedding, very ampleness is not necessary right?

Comment: Could you add your definition of $D$ being very ample? I agree with @DanielSchepler that usually I would use "$\phi$ is a closed immersion" as the definition.